# user id in custom user_register_submit

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have created a custom module to send mail containing registered user data.  I used `custom_user_register_submit` but I am not getting the registered user id.  Is there any method to get user id in a function?

Comment: Can you post your code which you are trying to implement for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `user_load`.

I think, you know the user login name (e.g. "example_user").
In that case you can use the following code:

```
$user_name = "example_user";
$account = user_load(array("name" => $user_name));
$user_id = $account->uid;
```

Comment: Thanks Men,

i also found another method i.e.

$edit = array_merge($form_state['values'],array());
$account = user_save('', $edit);
$uid = $account->uid;